# import jar without class path in scala

Tags: java, scala, jar, import

Is it possible to import a jar without setting a new class path in scala?

I've got A.scala with a main function that creates an object whose class is defined in B.scala.

So I would first compile B.scala with "scalac B.scala" and then run "scala A.scala" where the implicit class path is the current directory.

Now, I also want to import a jar and make use of a class in it in A.scala. But neither running "scala -cp abc.jar A.scala" nor "scala -cp 'abc.jar .' A.scala" works.

Comment: `scalac -cp abc.jar A.scala` should work

Comment: I would suggest to use a build tool (e.g., sbt). Will make your life much easier down the line when you are dealing with more than 2 classes.